# Error when using fit_params with GridsearchCV and some params are singletons

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I would like to use XGBoost's early stopping with GridSearchCV, but I'm getting interesting errors with some code that used to work before I upgraded some modules. Current versions:

- xgboost: 0.90
- scikit_learn: 0.22
- python: 3.6.5

Reproducible example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split

iris = load_iris()

x_train, x_validate, y_train, y_validate = train_test_split(
    iris['data'], 
    iris['target'], 
    random_state=7, 
    train_size=0.75
)

model = XGBRegressor()

grid_params = {
    'max_depth': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
    'subsample': [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],    
}

grid = GridSearchCV(
    model,
    cv=5,
    n_jobs=10,
    param_grid = grid_params,
    verbose=3,
    refit=True
)

fit_params = {
    'verbose': False,
    'early_stopping_rounds': 10,        
    'eval_set': [(
        x_validate,
        y_validate
    )],
}

grid.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    **fit_params
)
```

Resulting error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c17691f9afb9> in <module>
     41     x_train,
     42     y_train,
---> 43     **fit_params
     44 )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    650         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
    651         # make sure fit_params are sliceable
--> 652         fit_params_values = indexable(*fit_params.values())
    653         fit_params = dict(zip(fit_params.keys(), fit_params_values))
    654 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    235         else:
    236             result.append(np.array(X))
--> 237     check_consistent_length(*result)
    238     return result
    239 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    206     """
    207 
--> 208     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
    209     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    206     """
    207 
--> 208     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
    209     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _num_samples(x)
    150         if len(x.shape) == 0:
    151             raise TypeError("Singleton array %r cannot be considered"
--> 152                             " a valid collection." % x)
    153         # Check that shape is returning an integer or default to len
    154         # Dask dataframes may not return numeric shape[0] value

TypeError: Singleton array array(False) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

If I tweak my code slightly so that fit_params looks like this, it runs without errors, but then early stopping is no longer applied:

```
fit_params = {
    'eval_set': [(
        x_validate,
        y_validate
    )],
}
```

The fit_params values for the model are valid - I've checked this by running

```
model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    **fit_params
)
```

This works as expected, but it only fits one instance of the model, rather than running the grid search.

What's going on with my grid search, and is there a workaround for this?

## Update:

If I change it so that fit_params looks like this and set refit=False, the grid search runs without errors, but I'm not sure early stopping is being applied properly:

```
fit_params = {
    'verbose': [False],
    'early_stopping_rounds': [10],        
    'eval_set': [(
        x_validate,
        y_validate
    )],
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, I've faced a very similar issue using LightGBM and had to `manually` perform the grid search. I've came to the conclusion both are not supported, however this question makes me want to try and find a solution.

Comment: your code works fine using `sklearn:0.20.4` and `xgboost:0.82`

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a known issue with scikit-learn 0.22:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15805

For now there is a workaround posted here:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15805#issuecomment-562927893

```
cia05rf commented 3 days ago
Thanks, i think this is best sorted on the lightGBM git so i'll raise an issue there.

For anyone who does come across this i have found a work around by making the below changes to sklearn/model_selection/_search.py -> fit.

Currently at line 651

# make sure fit_params are sliceable
- fit_params_values = indexable(*fit_params.values())
- fit_params = dict(zip(fit_params.keys(), fit_params_values))
+# fit_params_values = indexable(*fit_params.values())
+# fit_params = dict(zip(fit_params.keys(), fit_params_values))
```